# How to set root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Ruby on Rails 3.1 app I have a link like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_url %>
```

On My dev. machine it renders a link with "localhost:3000". On production it renders a link with an IP Address like this "83.112.12.27:8080". I would like to force rails to render the domain address instead of the IP Address. How can I set root_url?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your routes set:

```
 root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

and in your links set:

```
<%=link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

It will render

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

So in your localhost It'd take you to

`http://localhost:3000/`

and in your production server It'd take you to

`http://yourdomian.com/`

and the `routes.rb` will render the `index` action of the controller `welcome` by default.

PS. you also need to remove `index.html` from `public` directory in order to use this.

---

UPDATE

A little bit more on routing:

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: And It will always take you to `/` no matter if it's on your server or on your localhost.

Comment: Hm. That worked. THX. That is interesting. root_url renders on the server the ip address. But root_path renders the domain address.

Comment: Routes with `_path` prefix are relative, they doesn't care on you ip address, Domain or port.

Answer (score 44):

You are looking for [ActionController's default url option](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options). So you can do something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "www.example.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

This also works for ActionMailer.  As well, both can be set in your environment .rb or application.rb

```
# default host for mailer
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: 'example.com', protocol: 'https://'
}

# default host for controllers
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  :host => "www.example.com"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked for me. But I preferred to do it in `application.rb` and added a `config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host=>"justinbiebiersucks.com"}`

Comment: Yes the application.rb is a more appropriate place. I don't remember why I've suggested that way. And love the example domain by the way ;)

Comment: @daemonsy upvoted your comment not only because it's useful but also for the jb reference :)

Comment: I like this answer. Yet I've been working to define a convenient way to define a convenient configuration variable that just works everywhere across various environments and boot modes. I suspect I will end up having to rely on something like ENV vars. Basically, I'll end up following 12 factor (http://12factor.net/config).

From there I can set whatever configuration variable I want in application.rb or environment/*

````# in application.rb
config.root_url = ENV['ROOT_HOST']
````

Then:
````
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: config.root_url, protocol: 'https://'
}
````

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could just do something like this in your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :home_uri

  def home_uri
    Rails.env.production? ? 'http://www.yourdomain.com' : root_url
  end
  ...
end
```

And then change your link to be like this: `<%= link_to 'Home', home_uri %>`

This makes a helper method, `home_uri`, which returns the url you desired if the application is being run in the development environment.  I don't think that you can easily overwrite `root_url`, and I also think it's likely a bad idea.  I had the helper method end with `uri` instead of `url` because rails uses the router to automatically create methods that end with `url`, so if you had a route named `home`, this solution won't overwrite or conflict with that named route helper method.  [You can read more about named route helper methods here if you're interested.](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)

Comment: Yes. I could do that. But that is not the purpose of "root_url". Is there no way to define "root_url" for different environments? I would like to define root_url in development.rb and production.rb.