# root_url on heroku - where is it getting 'Yourhost.com' from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Some confusion here. Using devise:invitable, and sending emails from heroku with the sendgrid add on.

On local, in the email that's generated when a user is invited, <%= root_url %> generates http://localhost:3000/ - which seems perfectly correct -
 but when deployed to heroku, when I receive the invite email, that same <%= root_url %> is coming out as http://yourhost.com/ ...why? Where's that set?

I thought root_url worked off routes.rb automatically and I have

```
root :to => 'home#splash'
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious? I added the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522813/how-to-set-root-url) to the application controller, but it has made no difference, the email still references http://yourhost.com/

Help appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your config/environments/production.rb set

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'www.yourdomain.com'}
```

You probably followed the Devise setup instructions displayed after you installed Devise which gets you to add

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

to your developments.rb file - but you just forgot about production.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was it. We'll wonder how ridiculous it was that I didn't manage to find yourhost.com when I did a find in files across the entire app another day. Thanks John.