# How are the protocol (e.g. http vs. https) and host components of Rails root_url determined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I'm trying to understand how the protocol and host components of `root_url` are determined, including any variation related to the environment (e.g. development vs. test vs. production).

The default seems to be "http" and "www.example.com", but I can't find where in Rails this is specified and whether/how it can be configured.

The question arose in the context of trying to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688059/ruby-on-rails-with-rspec-ssl-issue

None of the related questions I've seen (e.g. [How to set root_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522813/how-to-set-root-url)) address this.

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically figures out the protocol and domain based on the incoming request headers.

The only time you'll need to manually configure them is if you need to put links in emails generated by your application, because deep within ActionMailer, it doesn't have access to the request header information any more. So, then you'll just need to set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = ...` in each of your config/environments/*.rb files.

The reason you'll see `www.example.com` in tests is because that's what the tests will set the headers to. You should not need to change it.

Comment: So you're saying `root_url` refers to the most recently received request? Can you explain why `root_url` would have a value in an empty rspec test (i.e. one that simply examines `root_url` without performing any requests)?